# QtConcurrent::run - Passing Pointers Issue

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

I'm attempting to run a function concurrently using `QtConcurrent` but I'm running into issues with one of the arguments.

As a precursor, lets say I have the following classes and "interfaces":

```
class DataMessage : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    // ... fields and methods
};

class ITimeStampInfo {
    public:
        virtual QDateTime timestamp() const = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(ITimeStampInfo, "My.TimeStampInfo/1.0")

class IDataLengthInfo {
    public:
        virtual int dataLength() const = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(IDataLengthInfo, "My.IDataLengthInfo/1.0")

class DataMessage1 : public DataMessage, public ITimeStampInfo {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(ITimeStampInfo)
    // other fields, etc
    QDateTime timestamp() const;
};

class DataMessage2 : public DataMessage, public IDataLengthInfo {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(IDataLengthInfo)
    // other fields
    int dataLength() const;
};
```

And a class function called `processDataMessages`:

```
void MyClass::processDataMessages(DataMessage *msg) {
    // Previous to this function being called, concrete `DataMessage`
    // instances are created and passed by pointer into this function

    // Determine the data in the message
    IDataLengthInfo *dl = qobject_cast<IDataLengthInfo*>(msg);

    if (dl) {
        qDebug() << "Got a message with IDataLengthInfo";
    }

    ITimeStampInfo *ts = qobject_cast<ITimeStampInfo*>(msg);

    if (ts) {
        qDebug() << "Got a message with ITimeStampInfo";
    }

    // etc
}
```

This `processDataMessages` is called in a `slot`. During normal operation, this function works perfectly and the `qDebug()` statements execute as expected as the pointer is correct - for example, inspecting the pointer type in the debugger results in a `DataMessage1` type, for instance

I now want to run this function asynchronously as potentially, there may be a bit of work to do. If I try to execute this function using `QtConcurrent::run` from within the slot as follows:

```
void MyClass::dataReceived(DataMessage *msg) {
    // this->processDataMessages(msg);
    QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::processDataMessages, msg);
}
```

Now when I break on the first `qobject_cast` line in the `processDataMessages` function, I can see that the `msg` pointer is of type `DataMessage` and not any of the `DataMessage1` or `DataMessage2` types.

Something is being lost during the operation of `QtConcurrent::run` and its probably something dumb I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as it turns out, the following code works:

```
QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::processDataMessages, msg);
// Wait for the function to finish
f.waitForFinished();
```

Doesn't really seem any different to the original but something in the return value may be maintaining state??

Comment: I expect that `msg` is destructed in the function that calls `dataReceived`. By blocking your main thread using `waitForFinished`, you will not take advantage of the asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: Good point, it hadn't actually occurred to me that `waitForFinished` would block the main thread. Hmmm...